# Heroku deploy cannot find js filed

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

I tried to deploy my node.js app. Everything had worked well but it couldn't find the javascript files. This is the error:

> proove.herokuapp.com/:16 GET http://proove.herokuapp.com/js/Inputs.js 404 (Not Found)

this is the server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
app     = express() 
server  = require('http').createServer(app)
io      = require('socket.io').listen(server)

var users       = []
var positions   = []
var datas       = []
var ids         = []


server.listen(process.env.PORT||3000)

console.log("server running...")

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

})


io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){

console.log(ids.length + ": " + socket.id)  

ids.push(socket.id)
socket.broadcast.emit("obj", positions)

socket.on("created", function(data){

    console.log(data)
    positions.push(data)

})

socket.on("update", function(data){

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){

        if(ids[i] == socket.id){

            positions.splice(i,1,data)
            socket.broadcast.emit("obj", positions)

        }

    }

})

socket.on("loller", function(data){

    socket.broadcast.emit("lol",data)
    datas.push(data)

})
socket.on("Quit", function(data){

    datas = data
    socket.broadcast.emit("refr",1)

})

socket.on("disconnect",function(){

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){

        if(ids[i] == socket.id){

            positions.splice(i,1)
            ids.splice(i,1)

        }

    }
    users.pop()

})




 })
```

and this is my index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Lollipop</title>
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
    <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<canvas id = "canvas" width = "600" height = "400" style = "background-color:white"></canvas>
<script src = "js/Inputs.js"></script>
<script src = "js/main.js"></script>
<script src = "js/loader.js"></script>
<script src = "js/hud.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error could be because I use the free version

Comment: the file was not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
  app.use(express.static("public"))
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: I found the problem